# iOS Voice-to-Text is only reading 1 line in a multi-line UITextView

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

Getting started with accessibility for an iOS app and I've run into a snag.
I Googled around a lot but I didn't find much info on this specific issue.

I have a multi-line UITextView. Whenever I tap on it for the voice-to-text to read out, it reads the first line only and adds the last letter for the first word of the next line. Then it stops.

So if I have a UITextView that has:

> "Hello
>
> StackOverflow"

It will be read out as "Hello S".

Any idea what might be going on?

Answer (score 0):

Well in a classic `tell the rubber duck` style, I figured this out shortly after posting.

When I disabled the `User Interaction Enabled` flag in the identity inspector it fixed the issue.